# Integration of product under derivative?

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, indefinite-integrals

I have two expressions, they need to be the same and equal but I can`t see where I am making mistake:

$\int (p_0 dp_1+p_1 dp_0)=\int d(p_1p_0)$

On the other side, when I integrate both sides I have result:

$p_0p_1+p_1p_0+C_1=p_1p_0+C_2$

What I have missed here?

Comment: What are $p_0$ and $p_1$ and what does $d(p_0 p_1)$ mean to you?

Comment: $p_0$ and $p_1$ are pressures, how is that connected with that is it equation correct or not?

Comment: You assumed that $p_0$ and $p_1$ are constants, because you put them out of the integral in the left side of the equation. If they're not constants, then your integration on the left side is wrong.

Comment: Left side is wrong. For example if $p_0=p_1=p$ then $\int pdp+pdp =p^{2}/2+p^{2}/2+C=p{2}+C$ but you are taking it to be $p^{2}+p^{2}+C$

Comment: They are not constants, but isn`t is that like derivation of product $(uv)'=u'v+uv'$?

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy 
I understand that is my mistake, 2*something and left and right side are not equals, but I can`t understand why is that not correct? What principle did I miss?

Comment: Your first equation is correct (that is the principle in fact of integration by parts: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_parts). However, your last equation is wrong, because you need more information about $p_0$ and $p_1$ (e.g., a mathematical formula) to perform that integration. This is what @KaviRamaMurthy illustrates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\int (p_0 dp_1+p_1 dp_0)=\int d(p_1p_0)\qquad$ : This is correct.

$\int d(p_1p_0)=p_1p_0+C_2\qquad$ : This is correct.

$\int (p_0 dp_1+p_1 dp_0)=p_0p_1+p_1p_0+C_1\qquad$ : This is false.

Because $\quad\int p_0 dp_1 \neq p_0p_1+c_1\quad$ and $\quad\int p_1 dp_0  \neq p_1p_0+c_2$

One cannot integrate separately $\int p_0 dp_1$ and separately  $\int p_0 dp_1$. One have to integrate them together, that is $\int (p_0 dp_1+p_1 dp_0)$ in writing :
$$\int (p_0 dp_1+p_1 dp_0)=\int d(p_1p_0)=p_1p_0+C_2$$
The term on the right gives the result for the whole term on the left.

NOTE :

One can integrate $\int f(x)dx$ because the function $f(x)$ is function of the same variable than the variable of integration $x$.

One cannot integrate $\int f(x)dt$ because the function $f(x)$ is function of $x$ but not of $t$. More exactly, if $f(x)$ is function of $x$ only, not function of $x$ and $t$, then $\int f(x)dt=f(x)\int dt=f(x)(t+c)$.

One can integrate $\int f(x(t))dt$ because the function of function $f(x(t))$ is function of the same variable than the variable of integration $t$.

In the case $\int p_0dp_1$ it is not specified that $p_0$ is function of $p_1$. So, this is the same case as $\int f(x)dt$ above.